# How to add tags to docker images made using autobuild

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I've searched around and can't find a real answer to this. If I create a docker git repo and set up autobuild to my dockerhub account, it will build with a single tag (i.e. latest, or 1.0 or foo) but I can't find any way to add a tag afterwards as you can via command line with a locally built docker image. Pulling down the image and then retagging doesn't work as the autobuild repos are read-only outside of the webui.

Being able to manually add a tag to an existing build would satisfy me for now, but being able to script in something to grab the correct tag version would be the best solution.

Comment: A full answer to this is provided at ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328166/docker-hub-automated-build-tagging/31538378#31538378

Comment: A full answer to this is provided at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328166/docker-hub-automated-build-tagging/31538378#31538378

Answer (score 4):

You can do this through the UI somewhat indirectly:

- Select Automated Build

[image: Automated Build]

- Add a new build trigger

[image: Build Trigger]

- Select Tag from the drop down on the left
- Enter the git commit hash of the change you want tagged as the `Name`
- Enter the tag you want to add to your build
  [image: Tag]

Comment: That's a bit of a pain. I was hoping for a better way to do that. Currently the images I'm trying to build are archlinux ones, which only have the latest version of a package available. I was hoping to be able to tag a release as running service v1 or v2 etc to be able to roll back if a new version produces issues.

Comment: Any news on this? Is it possible to access the github tag in the "SomeTag" field by a variable? IMHO it would be nice to at least be able to re-use the same tag names on both sides.

Comment: This does not work for me, I get `Remote branch 5b7fe19b1cb333440118b1eb82741cd6ab4562ea not found in upstream origin`. It's like it's looking for a branch and not a commit id.

Comment: Did you change the drop down to tag and not branch?

Comment: aw, really does not work, same problem that@DanTenenbaum and yes I've selected tag