# Automate adding new repository tags to Docker Registry Automated Build

Tags: build, registry, docker

Is it possible with current featureset of Automated Build to add new tags from repository and tag the resulting image? Or do I need 3party service to automatically push new tags to Docker Registry?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  `docker push` will push tags to the registry.

Comment: @seanmcl `docker push` does not authenticate when pushing to an automated build repo, even if the image is just a tag. See [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/fata-0005-error-pushing-to-registry-authentication-is-required/1672/3) for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at this time.

There is currently (Oct 2014) no Docker Hub API to create new builds or tags, so Docker Hub Automated Builds will only build the tags you've entered manually through the web UI. If you want to keep adding tags automatically, you need to `docker push` your tagged images yourself.

Comment: As explained in the comment to the question above, `docker push` fails on an automated build repo. The web UI is the only way to add tags to an automated build repo, for now. It is a bit of a workaround, but this answer describes the process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092031/how-to-add-tags-to-docker-images-made-using-autobuild