# How do I make a Docker hub use the same image for "latest" and "vX.Y"?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Docker Hub builds a [Syncthing image](https://hub.docker.com/r/meonkeys/syncthing/) for me from [this source repo](https://github.com/meonkeys/docker-syncthing).

I tagged the [latest commit](https://github.com/meonkeys/docker-syncthing/commit/d3ef7a6cf24e9530b7c1723f900e0eb7a5fd7185) v0.13.5, but Docker built it twice: [once for `latest`](https://hub.docker.com/r/meonkeys/syncthing/builds/bzlm4fee4yjyngzecouubzv/) and [once for v0.13.5](https://hub.docker.com/r/meonkeys/syncthing/builds/bmefygwvfoewavn9lcexayc/).

Why? Shouldn't it be able to figure out the source is the same? Am I just doing something dumb in my [Dockerfile](https://github.com/meonkeys/docker-syncthing/blob/master/Dockerfile), breaking caching? Is there some way I need to hint to Docker Hub that this should really be two images with the same checksum but different tags?

I'm thinking of the two Docker image tags `latest` and `v0.13.5` like two git tags both pointing to the same commit. Shouldn't Docker Hub work that way too? If someone tries to pull `latest` they'd pull exactly the same image tagged `v0.13.5`? I know how to pull/re-tag/push, but again, seems like there just must be some way to get Docker Hub to do this automatically.

[Build settings](https://hub.docker.com/r/meonkeys/syncthing/~/settings/automated-builds/):

[image: screenshot of meonkeys/syncthing build settings]

Comment: I think I'm asking for a new feature. Filed here: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/712

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little magic, Docker Hub *can* do this! [Pablo Chico de Guzmán](https://github.com/pchico83) [helped me out](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/712#issuecomment-228263585).

Steps:

1. add a file called `hooks/post_push`
2. make `hooks/post_push` executable, commit and push
3. delete the "Branch" build, but leave the "Tag" build in place

Now, any tags I push (e.g. `git push --tags`) fire off an automated build, and the same image is also given the `latest` tag.

[Here's the change I had to make](https://github.com/meonkeys/docker-syncthing/commit/b9298d84ffbcee12100b3f053d4a8658d56a3647) so the most recent "vX.Y"-tagged `meonkeys/syncthing` image is also tagged `latest`.

[image: screenshot of Docker Hub build settings for my syncthing image]

Answer (score 2):

`Latest` is just  “the last build/tag that ran without a specific tag/version specified”.

If you push a tagged image it does not replace the current image tagged with latest. If you push tagged images only, `latest` tag is not added.

Automated Builds on Docker Hub is adding the `latest` tag automatically for the master branch.

Comment: You should be able to customize your autobuild tags: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/images/regex-help.png

Comment: I'm not pushing any images, Docker Hub builds and tags everything for me. (also added more detail to original question)